# Catching application crashes from Python os.system("application")

Tags: python

I am trying to use Python to start an application on my Mac and then catch any application errors such as crashes.  For example, launch TextEdit with a file, catch any exceptions hit, close TextEdit, Loop and use a new file.

I have tried os.system, but am not sure how to catch the crash exceptions log the issues for further investigation and continue?  Should I be using subprocess.call instead?

Can anyone point me in the right direction or has someone written a harness like this?  New Python programmer, thanks in advance.

Comment: An external program that crashes won't cause Python to raise an exception; you'll merely get the program's exit code as the return value of `os.system`.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely be using `subprocess`. It allows for much finer-grained control of external processes.